# Is there a best practice on setting up glibc on docker alpine linux base image?

Tags: docker, glibc, alpine-linux

Is there a best practice on setting up glibc on docker alpine linux base image with correct paths so any spawned process can correctly reference the location of the installed libc libraries?

Comment: The Alpine docks have a whole page dedicated to this... https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Running_glibc_programs

Answer (score 62):

Yes there is,

I've used a custom built glibc to install a JRE on it.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc)

You can use wget or curl to get the code and apk to install them

**UPDATED commands see comments below**

```
apk --no-cache add ca-certificates wget
wget -q -O /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub
wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.28-r0/glibc-2.28-r0.apk
apk add glibc-2.28-r0.apk
```

It worked perfectly for me

Comment: The updated commands are based on latest install instructions from https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc - these worked well

Answer (score 29):

Installing the glibc compatibility libraries has worked for me so far every time

`apk add gcompat`

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/gcompat

Comment: I'm just getting a ton of `symbol not found` errors with this when trying to execute binaries linked against glibc.

Comment: Turns out that was due to `libstdc++` missing. Installing that, too, makes things work for me :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had create a github repo [Docker build for glibc for alpine](https://github.com/puxos/alpine-pkg-glibc), support multi-arch, i.e. x86_64, aarch64, etc. You can build from the latest glibc source for any CPU type in just one line command. It was forked from [sgerrand's repo](https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc), I modified to support multi-arch and combine builder stage and packaging stage into one single line. Or you could just download the pre-built packages from release page.

Comment: when I run it I get ```E: The repository 'http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu disco-security Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu disco-proposed Release' does not have a Release file.```

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to **not** install glibc on Alpine Linux. It uses [musl libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/) instead, a lightweight, fast, simple and standards-conform C library (i.e. everything that glibc is not).

Instead of installing glibc on Alpine, build and/or package your dependent software packages and libraries for Alpine.

- For python packages, the setup.py program will often recompile, rather than downloading a prebuild binary, when run on Alpine.
- For java, use alpine openjdk instead of Oracle.
- For faiss, and other numpy-dependent libraries in python (copied from https://gist.github.com/orenitamar/f29fb15db3b0d13178c1c4dd611adce2)

```
    FROM alpine:3.4
    RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/main" > /etc/apk/repositories
    RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
    RUN apk --no-cache --update-cache add gcc gfortran python python-dev py-pip build-base wget freetype-dev libpng-dev openblas-dev
    RUN ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h
    RUN pip install numpy scipy pandas matplotlib
```

Comment: Because there is no good alternative. Java, python, node and other frameworks need glibc, musl is not supported (or not really). So either use use a big base image, or you use alpine with ported glibc

Comment: Using musl_libc is like Jeff Bezos saying that from now on Amazon will only do business in Latin.

Comment: " a lightweight, fast, simple " nope. it's surely not fast - that's the reason i want replace it

Answer (score 1):

Use below

```
RUN apk add --no-cache gcompat libstdc++
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Alpine Linux uses musl libc, a lightweight, fast, simple and standards-conform C library. To run glibc compiled apps in Alpine we should add two libs provided.  RUN apk add --no-cache gcompat libstdc++

Comment: Could you please edit that into your answer instead?

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback off of [carlomas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38433396/6253592), downloading and installing from the repo is the way to go. But on newer versions of Alpine it will throw when installing glibc due to a clash with `alpine-baselayout`. For more context, see [this issue](https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/issues/185).

The current workaround for that is to force an override when installing glibc. You can add the flag like this:

```
apk --no-cache add --force-overwrite glibc-<GLIBC_VER>.apk
```

Followed by a reinstall of the package it clashes with:

```
apk add --force-overwrite alpine-baselayout-data
```

This should solve the `ERROR: glibc-<GLIBC_VER>: trying to overwrite etc/nsswitch.conf owned by alpine-baselayout-data-<BASELAYOUT_VER>.` error you might see.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `karrelin/glibc-alpine` on the docker hub.

It builds glibc from scratch to get the latest glibc release!

Here's a example dockerfile utilizing the `karrelin/glibc-alpine` docker image

```
FROM karrelin/glibc-alpine:latest

RUN apk add tini

ENTRYPOINT ["tini" "--"]

CMD ["/bin/ash"]
```