# Alpine linux in Docker container => `env: can't execute 'node': No such file or directory`

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux

I am installing Node.js version 8 in an Alpine linux container like so:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache wget

RUN wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v8.1.1/node-v8.1.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN sudo tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xzf node-v8.1.1-linux-x64.tar.gz

RUN ls -l /usr/local/bin/node
RUN ls -l /usr/local/bin/npm

RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node
RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm

ENV PATH "/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
RUN echo "PATH env variable => '$PATH'"
```

`/usr/local/bin/node` and `/usr/local/bin/npm` exist, and npm somehow is indeed recognized at the command line. But for the node executable, I get this error:

```
Step 23/53 : RUN npm cache clean -f
 ---> Running in 8bbc96b88935
env: can't execute 'node': No such file or directory
```

I can confirm that the $PATH variable includes both

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
```

e.g.:

```
Step 19/53 : RUN echo "PATH env variable => '$PATH'"
 ---> Running in c5227e6e3db0
PATH env variable => '/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
```

so why can't `env` find the node executable? So weird.

Here is a clue:

```
Step 10/52 : RUN ldd /usr/local/bin/node
 ---> Running in db210653f0ed
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fefae36b000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fefae36b000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fefae36b000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fefae36b000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fefae36b000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fefae36b000)
Error loading shared library libstdc++.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bin/node)
Error loading shared library libgcc_s.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bin/node)
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE9pbackfailEi: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt13runtime_errorC2ERKSs: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt19__throw_logic_errorPKc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt9exceptionD2Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSsC1ERKSs: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt17__throw_bad_allocv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs6appendEmc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE6xsgetnEPcl: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo9_M_insertIyEERSoT_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt18basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt19basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _Znwm: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt11logic_errorC2ERKSs: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5imbueERKSt6locale: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs6assignEPKc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTv0_n24_NSoD1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5closeEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNKSt13runtime_error4whatEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTv0_n24_NSt14basic_ofstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEED0Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __isinf: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __cxa_demangle: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs9push_backEc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE7copyfmtERKS2_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSolsEi: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt16__throw_bad_castv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __cxa_guard_acquire: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNKSs4findEcm: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE4initEPSt15basic_streambufIcS1_E: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt7getlineIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEERSt13basic_istreamIT_T0_ES7_RSbIS4_S5_T1_ES4_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZdaPv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo9_M_insertIlEERSoT_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __cxa_allocate_exception: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: backtrace_symbols: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo9_M_insertIbEERSoT_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs6resizeEmc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15__exception_ptr13exception_ptrC1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt13runtime_errorD2Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNKSt14error_category10equivalentERKSt10error_codei: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs12_M_leak_hardEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNKSs17find_first_not_ofEPKcmm: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _Znam: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo9_M_insertIPKvEERSoT_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNKSt5ctypeIcE13_M_widen_initEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt18_Rb_tree_decrementPSt18_Rb_tree_node_base: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo5writeEPKcl: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo5flushEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo9_M_insertImEERSoT_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt12__basic_fileIcED1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTv0_n24_NSoD0Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNKSt15basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE3strEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSsC1EPKcmRKSaIcE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZdlPv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo3putEc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE7seekoffElSt12_Ios_SeekdirSt13_Ios_Openmode: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTv0_n24_NSt14basic_ofstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEED1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __cxa_guard_release: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs9_M_mutateEmmm: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt19basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1ESt13_Ios_Openmode: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNKSs5rfindEcm: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE7seekposESt4fposI11__mbstate_tESt13_Ios_Openmode: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs6appendEPKcm: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __gxx_personality_v0: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs4swapERSs: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSoD0Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSsC1EmcRKSaIcE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt20__throw_length_errorPKc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt20__throw_out_of_rangePKc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __cxa_throw: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt11logic_errorD2Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE7_M_syncEPcmm: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _Unwind_Resume: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __popcountdi2: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs6appendEPKc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5rdbufEPSt15basic_streambufIcS1_E: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __register_atfork: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __isnan: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNKSt14error_category23default_error_conditionEi: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE9showmanycEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt18condition_variableD1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs4_Rep9_S_createEmmRKSaIcE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs14_M_replace_auxEmmmc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt8ios_baseD2Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs6insertEmPKcm: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt21__throw_runtime_errorPKc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo9_M_insertIdEERSoT_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt14basic_ofstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEED1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt6localeC1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs6assignEPKcm: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs4_Rep10_M_disposeERKSaIcE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs6assignERKSs: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs6appendERKSs: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEEC1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt18basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1ESt13_Ios_Openmode: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNKSs4findEPKcmm: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt28_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erasePSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseRS_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE9underflowEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __cxa_free_exception: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt18_Rb_tree_incrementPKSt18_Rb_tree_node_base: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15__exception_ptr13exception_ptrD1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSoD1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __cxa_pure_virtual: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt14basic_ofstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEED0Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __dynamic_cast: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE4openEPKcSt13_Ios_Openmode: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt18_Rb_tree_incrementPSt18_Rb_tree_node_base: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs4_Rep10_M_destroyERKSaIcE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNKSt14error_category10equivalentEiRKSt15error_condition: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt8ios_baseC2Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt6localeD1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZnwmRKSt9nothrow_t: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5uflowEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt18_Rb_tree_decrementPKSt18_Rb_tree_node_base: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSsC1ERKSsmm: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNKSs7compareEPKc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt29_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalancebPSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseS0_RS_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZdlPvRKSt9nothrow_t: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5clearESt12_Ios_Iostate: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSsD1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: backtrace: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSsC1EPKcRKSaIcE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE6setbufEPcl: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo9_M_insertIxEERSoT_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs7reserveEm: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTISt14error_category: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTISt11logic_error: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTISt9exception: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTISt13runtime_error: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt8__detail12__prime_listE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVSt14error_category: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt7nothrow: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVSt15basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv121__vmi_class_type_infoE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVSt19basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTTSt14basic_ofstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVSt14basic_ofstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVSt18basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTTSt18basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTTSt19basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE: symbol not found
The command '/bin/sh -c ldd /usr/local/bin/node' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

after running this new call:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache libstdc++ && apk add --no-cache libgcc
```

I still get an error:

```
Step 12/54 : RUN ldd /usr/local/bin/node
 ---> Running in deecef947d0b
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9266dee000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9266dee000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9266dee000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x7f9266a9c000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9266dee000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x7f926688a000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9266dee000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f9266dee000)
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __isinf: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: backtrace_symbols: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __register_atfork: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __isnan: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: backtrace: symbol not found
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Alpine distro is based on a libc variant called [*musl-libc*](https://www.musl-libc.org/). The **node** binary you are installing is compiled against *glibc*, as most (all?) other standard distros use the more commonly used *glibc* standard library.

One option is to add glibc to your alpine distro base, and then if you were truly unable to compile node against *musl-libc* you could allow the glibc support you added handle the mismatch. There are other [stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818831/is-there-a-best-practice-on-setting-up-glibc-on-docker-alpine-linux-base-image) which provide details on how to do this.

**However**, I think the best case scenario is for you to use a node binary built against Alpine's *musl-libc*. This is the way the official node images handle the alpine tag variant. You can see how they do that here in the [official Node 12.4.0 release Dockerfile](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/5d8827883ba24066cec73f6d6c3e70c3ec4e1b28/12/alpine/Dockerfile) for node's alpine variant. Of course your build will be longer to **build** node versus **download** a pre-built binary, but it will simplify any complications around trying to shoehorn glibc support into Alpine.

Comment: That seems more precise than my answer. +1

Comment: @Phil E: The link you posted to `official image Dockerfile` is broken.

Comment: Thanks for the notification--I've updated it to Node 12.4 and made it a direct link to a commit so it should be long-lived.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is no missing dependencies that might be missing for node to execute: add an `ldd /usr/local/bin/node`

It could be the case the base (Alpine) image used has some dependencies missing for node to work: you can test if the issue persists when you change said base image (with an ubuntu one for instance)

The fact that ldd mentions missing dynamic libraries/symbols explains the error message.

See how node is built from [its Dockerfile](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/b502aa016335c81a586b430328d8fee4897ee440/8.4/Dockerfile):

```
FROM buildpack-deps:jessie
```

Ie: it installs on top of a much complete image than an alpine one.

It would be easier to use the node image directly, and build from it.

Comment: So yeah, given the output, I tried this: `RUN apk add --no-cache libstdc++ &&  apk add --no-cache libgcc`

Comment: right but the problem is that i need to use a different image, in my case `FROM docker:dind`, so as far as I know, this gives me little choice but to install node.js manually.

Comment: @AlexanderMills In that case, https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/b502aa016335c81a586b430328d8fee4897ee440/8.4/Dockerfile illustrates how that installation actually takes place.

Comment: thanks, yeah I need to get node.js inside a container like this: `docker run --privileged --name some-docker -d docker:stable-dind`

Comment: @AlexanderMills Did you try adding node from the dind image (whose Dockerfile is https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/e68e4e6ec06c055a95d441144b0e34d0872f2665/17.06/dind/Dockerfile)

Comment: I was using `FROM docker:dind` in this original question...I assume it's all Alpine and it's posing a problem to install Node with Alpine. Alpine's apk manager can install Node.js version 7, but I don't see version 8 available.