# VSCode remote server.sh not finding node in wsl docker-desktop

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, remote-server, docker-desktop

I have:

VSCode v1.46.0

remote-wsl extension v0.44.3

Windows 10 OS build 19041.329

Docker Desktop v2.3.0.3

I am trying to open VSCode within the docker-desktop wsl and I get the below error every time. I have gone to the directory listed and see the node file I am not sure what to do?

```
[2020-06-17 20:30:27.337] Resolving wsl+docker-desktop, resolveAttempt: 1
[2020-06-17 20:30:27.462] Starting VS Code Server inside WSL (docker-desktop)
[2020-06-17 20:30:27.463] Extension version: 0.44.3, Windows build: 19041. Multi distro support: available. WSL path support: enabled
[2020-06-17 20:30:27.751] Probing if server is already installed: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d docker-desktop -e sh -c "[ -d ~/.vscode-server/bin/a5d1cc28bb5da32ec67e86cc50f84c67cc690321 ] && printf found || ([ -f /etc/alpine-release ] && printf alpine-; uname -m)"
[2020-06-17 20:30:28.100] Probing result: found
[2020-06-17 20:30:28.100] Server install found in WSL
[2020-06-17 20:30:28.101] Launching C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d docker-desktop sh -c '"$VSCODE_WSL_EXT_LOCATION/scripts/wslServer.sh" a5d1cc28bb5da32ec67e86cc50f84c67cc690321 stable .vscode-server 0  ' in c:\Users\Eric\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.44.3}
[2020-06-17 20:30:28.345] Setting up server environment: Looking for /root/.vscode-server/server-env-setup. Not found.
[2020-06-17 20:30:28.345] WSL version: 4.19.104-microsoft-standard docker-desktop
[2020-06-17 20:30:28.345] WSL2-shell-PID: 1036
[2020-06-17 20:30:28.345] Starting server: /root/.vscode-server/bin/a5d1cc28bb5da32ec67e86cc50f84c67cc690321/server.sh  --port=0 --use-host-proxy --enable-remote-auto-shutdown 
[2020-06-17 20:30:28.347] /root/.vscode-server/bin/a5d1cc28bb5da32ec67e86cc50f84c67cc690321/server.sh: line 12: /root/.vscode-server/bin/a5d1cc28bb5da32ec67e86cc50f84c67cc690321/node: not found
[2020-06-17 20:30:28.347] VS Code Server for WSL closed unexpectedly.
[2020-06-17 20:30:28.347] For help with startup problems, go to
[2020-06-17 20:30:28.347] https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_wsl-tips
[2020-06-17 20:30:29.404] WSL Daemon exited with code 0
```

Comment: I have the same issue when opening a window in WSL. I have a remote-container window in parallel, where the same code of the vs code server is executed inside of a docker container. So I guess, something is missing in the docker-desktop distribution to launch node. Replacing node by pointing to a local node installation did not help me. Still investigating further.

Answer (score 11):

Had a very similar problem today. VScode been working for a long time and stopped today suddenly.

```
/home/user/.vscode-server/bin/b5afea7e86cc50f84c67cc690321/server.sh --port=0 --use-host-proxy --enable-remote-auto-shutdown
VS Code Server for WSL closed unexpectedly
```

In `WSL` console, the `server.sh` is empty somehow. 
My resolution: Remove `WSL` extension. `rm -rf ./vscode-server`. Reinstall `WSL` extension to reconstruct the corrupted file.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that the vscode-server, which is installed to the WSL, is not compatible with the distro given by Docker Desktop. You should use an official Linux distribution from Microsoft Store, i.e. Ubuntu.

The docker-desktop distro is coming from Alpine Linux which is based on a libc variant called musl-libc. But the vscode-server, which is installed by the wsl extension is build against glibc.

You can see this by doing this in wsl:
`apk update && apk add binutils` and then

```
readelf -l /root/.vscode-server/bin/a5d1cc28bb5da32ec67e86cc50f84c67cc690321/node | grep "program interpreter"
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

But in Alpine, this library does not exist and that is why the error message reports `not found`.

So I was wondering, why the vscode server is working inside of an Alpine container with the Remote Container extension. For example starting `alpine:3.9`, the above check shows the following:

```
readelf -l /root/.vscode-server/bin/a5d1cc28bb5da32ec67e86cc50f84c67cc690321/node | grep "program interpreter"
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1]
```

For some reason, the Remote-Container extension has some detection mechanism for Alpine and is using a different build of the vscode server. My suggestion is, that you can file an issue on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues for this problem.
Otherwise, use another WSL distro or use the container extension.

Some references on this topic:

- [Alpine linux in Docker container => `env: can't execute 'node': No such file or directory`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45973481/alpine-linux-in-docker-container-env-cant-execute-node-no-such-file-or)
- Even Alpine for WSL is supposed to work https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1054
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/linux

Answer (score 1):

In my case the fix to this was:

- open Docker for Windows settings
- untick "Use the WSL 2 base engine" then click "Apply & Restart"
- tick "Use the WSL 2 base engine" again then click "Apply & Restart"

The next time I ran "Remote WSL: New Window" it connected again properly

Comment: This works for me after updating docker. I was getting the error `.vscode-server/server-env-setup not found` on WSL.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to restart WSL

```
wsl --shutdown
wsl
```

Comment: Is that _all_ you had to do? Or was this in _addition_ to one of the existing answers?

Comment: That's all I had to do.

Comment: Worked perfectly fine for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For me the cause was the `/etc/wsl.conf` file on my Debian instance. I disabled automount a while back, but this is necessary for the WSL extension to work. So I put it back on, and it worked.

```
[automount]
enabled = true
```