# VS code server for WSL closed unexpectedly, I can't do anything in vs code. How do I fix it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

does anyone know what this means? I get this message every time I try to open a folder in VS code and when I'm using ubuntu and run `code .` nothing happens
[image]

Comment: This workaround worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66080316/1800052