# Install node.js official binary on alpine

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to install node official binary on alpine docker.

`wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.4.0/node-v14.4.0-linux-x64.tar.xz`

`tar -xvf node-v14.4.0-linux-x64.tar.xz`
And once I try to run it:

```
~/node-v14.4.0-linux-x64/bin # ./node 
sh: ./node: not found
```

Although the file is here, I have the permission and it is executable

```
~/node-v14.4.0-linux-x64/bin # ls -la
total 70376
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Oct  7 11:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 1001 1001     4096 Oct  7 11:53 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 72052312 Jun  2 14:33 node
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       38 Oct  7 11:53 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       38 Oct  7 11:53 npx -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
```

When I do the same action on ubuntu it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because alpine uses `musl` instead of `glibc`, and the binaries distributed from node's website are built against `glibc`.

Here are a few solutions for your problem, in order of preference (and why):

1. **Use [node's official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) instead of trying to install it from a alpine base image**: that's because there are different dependencies and things to setup before having a working node image (certificates, tls libraries, etc). *This is the most recommended.*
2. **Installing node via `apk`:** node is available at alpine's official package manager apk, and you can install it by simply running `apk add nodejs`. The only problem here is that the version that's available in the repository is the LTS (12.18.4 as of 2020-10-07).
3. **Installing/building a compability layer for `glibc` in alpine:** this is not recommended at all, since alpine is built over `musl` and running `glibc` *is not a good practice and can lead to things breaking*. Even installing the official `libc6-compat` may lead to problems:

Running node using libc6-compat:

```sh
$ ./node
Error relocating ./node: gnu_get_libc_version: symbol not found
Error relocating ./node: __register_atfork: symbol not found
Error relocating ./node: __strdup: symbol not found
Error relocating ./node: setcontext: symbol not found
Error relocating ./node: makecontext: symbol not found
Error relocating ./node: backtrace: symbol not found
Error relocating ./node: getcontext: symbol not found
```

Running node using [this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38433396/6580047) suggestion for `glibc`:

```sh
$ ./node
./node: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Stick to node's official image (solution 1) and things should work out fine :)

Comment: Why does apk only use the latest node? I currently have something similar happening, will your solutions work for me? My problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76534357/how-to-install-node-16-inside-of-a-buildspec-yamls-install-step-within-an-alpin

Comment: how do we do #1 in the context of pulling in a dockerfile for a bash script?

Comment: As alternative you can just copy steps from official nodejs docker image that is e.g. https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/1a2a796a6fecfda1f23f24551f2937f6b61830c6/16/alpine3.18/Dockerfile

Answer (score 5):

You need to download an unofficial build that is built against musl

```
wget https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/v14.4.0/node-v14.4.0-linux-x64-musl.tar.xz
```

Note: Unofficial builds are linked in the [Node.js project](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) then from my point of view does no represent a security issue.

Comment: You lose support for different platforms (such as M1 macs) by using a hardcoded platform build (x64 in this example).

Answer (score 3):

I tried using the old repositories but, found [Sr. Libre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6471502/sr-libre)'s above answer was the easiest to use.

add the following to the Dockerfile

```
RUN wget https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/v12.22.3/node-v12.22.3-linux-x64-musl.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf node-v12.22.3-linux-x64-musl.tar.gz
RUN rm node-v12.22.3-linux-x64-musl.tar.gz

RUN ln -s /var/www/node-v12.22.3-linux-x64-musl/bin/node /usr/bin/node
RUN ln -s /var/www/node-v12.22.3-linux-x64-musl/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```

Check from Docker container and you will see proper versions:

```
bash-5.1# node --version
v12.22.3
bash-5.1# npm -v
6.14.13
bash-5.1#
```

Following URL contains a list of builds you can use:

> https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/

Just ensure you pick the ones with `musl` suffix.

Comment: Failing in `wget` command, some connection issue

Answer (score 0):

Other binary don't work on alpine, need to build it manually as in here https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/80ded64083b5c9be7853d9d3634a22a96e15e92d/14/alpine3.10/Dockerfile

Comment: Try including the content of the Dockerfile and a reference to it, since the repository can change/go down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multi-stage build to copy the necessary files from the node:XX.XX.X-alpine image to your custom image. In the example below, the first FROM statement pulls the Node.js image tagged 18.17.1-alpine, and the second FROM statement initializes a new stage for your custom image in this example fpm_dev. The COPY --from=node lines then copy various directories from the node image to your custom image. hth

```
# Use the official Node.js Alpine image as the first stage
FROM node:18.17.1-alpine AS node

# Initialize the second stage with your custom image
FROM fpm_dev AS cli_dev

# Copy Node.js, npm, and yarn related files and directories from the first stage to the second stage
COPY --from=node /usr/lib /usr/lib                      # Libraries
COPY --from=node /usr/local/share /usr/local/share      # Shared assets and data
COPY --from=node /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib          # More libraries
COPY --from=node /usr/local/include /usr/local/include  # Header files
COPY --from=node /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin          # Binaries
COPY --from=node /opt /opt                              # Optional software packages
```